# Is there any way to show scrollbar in child div when I don't know the length of parent div

Tags: css, angular, angular-flex-layout

I have a parent div, as it's a sub section of whole complicated page, I can't get it's actual height.
Is there a way to show a vertical scrollbar in child div?

```
<div id="parent" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  <div id="title">This is title</div>
  <div id="children" style="flex: 1 1 auto; overflow-y: auto;">
     thousand lines...
  </di>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on the `#parent` ancestors, if they allow the `#parent` to "calculate" its height. So it really depends on the how the whole page css is defined.. If you can post an example full page we could help more. for example, does adding a `height:100%` to the `#parent` show the scrollbar ?

Answer (score -1):

Use `overflow-y: scroll`

[mdn reference on overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)